# Using css3 translate instead of position: left

Tags: jquery, css, css-animations, translate-animation

Why Moving Elements With Translate() Is Better Than Pos:abs Top/left
[Reference article](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/)
*Paul Irish*

For the life of me, I cannot get this css3 translate animation to work.  So I made a jquery interaction that has the same to behavior.  click on the X `.navi-toggle` in the top left corner to see it in action.  It's rather jerky and I'm really curious on how much better translate() will work.

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/matthewharwood/pen/ixfKC)

**HTML**

```
<div id="page-container"> 
  <nav id="route-bar" >
  </nav>
  <div class="w-panel">
      <div class="navi-toggle">X</div>
      <div class="panel">
  </div><!--end of w-panel-->
</div><!--end of page container-->
```

**CSS**

```
.open-panel
    {
        left:336px;

    }
```

**coffeescript**

```
$(".navi-toggle").on
  click: ->
    $(".w-panel").toggleClass "open-panel"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this gets you a bit closer. Based on your CodePen example you really just need to animate the `width`, which could be done using `keyframes` or possibly a `transition`.

**CSS**

```
.open-panel {
    -webkit-animation-duration: 2s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:1;
    -webkit-animation-name: slideOver;
    -webkit-transform:translateX(90%);
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideOver {
    from {
      -webkit-transform:translateX(0%);
    }
    to {
      -webkit-transform:translateX(90%);
    }
}
```

Here's the [full jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/SFVuW/) (apologies on the -webkit prefix, hopefully this gets you started).

Answer (score -2):

I have no idea about translate but you can use margin instead.